# Oracle Business Intelligence and EPM (Enterprise Performance Management)

Tags: oracle, button, tabs, business-intelligence

I am integrating Oracle BI with EPM. I am facing an error on Oracle EPM configuration. My buttons and tabs does not respond on click. I can move through navigation but buttons and tabs click does not respond.

Have anybody faced this issue? or know what might possible error be. Any kind of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in VMWare ? It usually happens in that case.

If you are using Windows, try closing the configuration utility, and (re)connect via Remote Desktop (RDP).